# Установка mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi

Столкнулась с такой проблемой. Установила mpi4py, при  запуске выводит  ошибку

`from mpi4py import MPI
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура.`

Так же установила openmpi и потом  уже microsoft mpi, но все равно ошибка не уходит. 
Как можно пофиксить эту ошибку?

Comment: А попробуйте whl установиться из https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mpi4py

Comment: Спасибо, все пофиксилось

Comment: Тогда напишите ваши шаги к решению и закройте вопрос, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было следующее:

1. Удаление mpi4py через pip uninstall mpi4py
2. Переустановка Microsoft mpi
3. Скачивание пакета mpi4py файлом с расширением whl
4. Добавление в папку с проектом
5. установка пакета с расширением whl